# Oracle Big Data Lite 2.5 VM Install

Tags: oracle, virtual-machine, bigdata

Trying to install BigDataLite VM. Following the instructions as specified here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/bigdata-appliance/bigdatalite-quickdeploy-25-2175583.pdf

After downloading the BigDataLite-xxx.zip.001 file, I tried extracting it with both 7-Zip and WinRAR. Both times I received errors saying 'Can not open file 'C:\Users...\Desktop\BigDataLite-2.5.zip' as archive'

I tried repairing the zipped file and then extracting and still received the same issue. I also tried renaming the zipped file, but still no luck.

Another user has received the same issue but has found no resolution. Any ideas here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into issues unzipping the first file as well. It seems that you need to download all the files into one folder. Then rename each of them so they look like "BigDataLite-xxx.zip.001, BigDataLite-xxx.zip.002,,, .zip.003, .zip.004, .zip.005, .zip.006"--not "BigDataLite-xxx(01).zip.zip, etc.".

Then, make sure you have 7zip (64 bit version) installed on Windows (I tried to do this on my mac but could not figure it out without 7zip). Right-click on "BigDataLite-xxx.zip.001" and hover over 7zip and select "extract here". It will work! I almost promise! :)

I hope this helps someone out!! I spent hours on this!

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick, please download md5sum and check the MD5 checksum value for all the files attached and there is a mismatch of these values for file 005 and 006, 005 checksum value is matching with 006 cheksum value and 006 value is matching with 005.

Rename 005 file as 006 and 006 as 005 then run 7zip, it will uncompress all files and generates BigDataLite-2.5.ova file and then import it in virtual box. It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm still a little confused. There are six of these BigData files to download. They are named BigDataLite-2.5.zip.001 - BigDataLite-2.5.zip.006. You are saying that there is an issue between 005 and 006 zip files. But I experience the error when I try to unzip the first one, 001. Did you have this same issue? Or was it with the 005 and 006 packages?

Comment: You need to unzip only 001 using 7zip, it will extract all the files. Rename BigDataLite-2.5.zip.006 as BigDataLite-2.5.zip.0061
Rename BigDataLite-2.5.zip.005 as BigDataLite-2.5.zip.006
Rename BigDataLite-2.5.zip.0061 as BigDataLite-2.5.zip.006

Then extract Rename BigDataLite-2.5.zip.001 with 7zip

Answer (score 0):

You need to unzip only 001 using 7zip, it will extract all the files. Rename BigDataLite-2.5.zip.006 as BigDataLite-2.5.zip.0061 Rename BigDataLite-2.5.zip.005 as BigDataLite-2.5.zip.006 Rename BigDataLite-2.5.zip.0061 as BigDataLite-2.5.zip.006 Then extract BigDataLite-2.5.zip.001 with 7zip

Comment: I understand those steps. Problem is I can't even unzip the 001 file. I've tried 7zip and WinRAR. I get an error every time I try.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue. 
In my case it was simply solved by deleting the files format (as I understood from developer guide, these files should be downloaded without any archive extension type , but download manager was too "clever" and added this extention).

Folder Options -> View tab -> Advanced settings -> clear the "Hide extensions for known file types" check box -> rename files by deleting ".zip" -> try to unzip again.

Hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

After you downloaded the files, windows explorer should show exactly all the extension with numeric suffix.  Please note 7zip does not need extension to end with .zip. It can only extract when the extension is in numeric sequence (.001,.002,.003, etc)

Comment: Please consider relating those facts to the question.  It's difficult to understand the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to include all the files (.001 to .007) before extracting .001